# rvm system install, bins not properly symlinked

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and installed rvm system wide with:
`$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable`

So far I've always performed single user installs and to he honest I'm quite confused by the results of the system wide install.
It did put the rvm bin directory in my path, but it symlinked all the binaries with names that can't be directly used.
Does it mean that I should symlink them one by one?
Did something go wrong?
Is that the defalt behaviour?

```
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ ll
total 60
drwxrwsr-x  2 root     rvm   4096 Apr  5 13:11 ./
drwxrwsr-x 23 root     rvm   4096 Apr  5 13:04 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm    578 Apr  5 13:04 bundle*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     41 Apr  5 13:11 erb-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/erb*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     48 Apr  5 13:11 erb-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/erb*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     41 Apr  5 13:11 gem-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gem*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     48 Apr  5 13:11 gem-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gem*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     41 Apr  5 13:11 irb-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/irb*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     48 Apr  5 13:11 irb-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/irb*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm    556 Apr  5 13:04 rake*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     42 Apr  5 13:11 rake-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rake*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     49 Apr  5 13:11 rake-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/rake*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     42 Apr  5 13:11 rdoc-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rdoc*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     49 Apr  5 13:11 rdoc-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/rdoc*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     40 Apr  5 13:11 ri-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/ri*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     47 Apr  5 13:11 ri-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/ri*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     42 Apr  5 13:11 ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/ruby*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     49 Apr  5 13:11 ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/ruby*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   1307 Apr  5 13:04 rvm*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   1512 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-auto-ruby*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   1803 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-exec*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm  13130 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-installer*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   3850 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-prompt*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   2263 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-shell*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm    648 Apr  5 13:04 rvm-smile*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root     rvm   2229 Apr  5 13:04 rvmsudo*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     44 Apr  5 13:11 testrb-ruby-2.0.0-p0 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0/testrb*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 appusr   rvm     51 Apr  5 13:11 testrb-ruby-2.0.0-p0@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/testrb*
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ 
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ 
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ 
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ which ruby
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ which irb
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ which gem
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ /usr/bin/env ruby -v
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Ask your administrator to install one of them
appusr@server-name:/usr/local/rvm/bin$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found what was wrong. Apparently `rvm` wasn't properly loaded as a function, that is
`$ type rvm | head -n 1`
didn't return "rvm is a function", but something like "rvm is hashed" (...?...).

It is also interesting that the problem wasn't limited to the system wide install. I imploded the system wide **rvm** install, removed the references in `/etc`, and installed it again without `sudo`... same problem.

I'd say it was my fault, and by "my" I mean that I wasn't aware of how **bash** handles some user switches. It may be useful to others as well, so I'll report  what I did.

I had ssh'd into the server as a general user and then switched to the user who will run the rails stack: `su appusr` (using bash).

After that, I installed `rvm` using:
`$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

---

When I tried the system wide install I of course also added the user to the **rvm** group with:
`$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm appusr`

---

...and logged out and in again: `exit`, and again `su appusr`.

Now, it seems that by doing so **bash** was only sourcing `~/.bashrc`, and not `~/.bash_profile` where rvm had placed the statement to load `rvm` as a function:
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Still, the `rvm` binary was in my **PATH**, and I could issue the commands needed to install ruby.
So far, so good.
The problem was that after the installation it somehow failed to select the **only** `ruby` I had installed as the default interpreter, and so it didn't create the symlinks.

I noticed it because when I issued `rvm list` I was presented with:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

... notice how it was **NOT** marked with `=*`.
I used the command `rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0 --default`, and I was warned that rvm wasn't *loaded as a function* and that something could not work (can't rememeber the exact message).

That was a breakthrough, and as I sourced `~/.bash_profile` I could successfully select that `ruby` and all the symlinks (`ruby`, `irb`, `rake`, etc) were immediately created.

That wasn't ideal, though.
The default setup of my `$HOME` folder has the usual three files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` (plus the ones for `zsh`).
`~/.bash_profile` was added by the **rvm** installation, and I'm having it source `~/.profile`.
`~/.profile`, then, automatically sources `~/.bashrc` if **bash** is being used.

As I said, however, by doing `su appusr` **bash** just sources `~/.bashrc`, and so fails to parse the statement loading *rvm as a function*. Very annoying.
Telling `~/.bashrc` to source `~/.bash_profile` would need some sort of control (an ENV variable?) to avoid an infinite reference loop, and seemed overkilling...
So I just moved `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into `~/.bashrc`, and I'd say everything seems to work now.

Comment: and it's all about enabling login shell in terminal emulator - check https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, rvm pointed me to that page when it warned me, but I'm using a mac and I couldn't find any _Terminal.app_ option similar to the one available to _gnome-terminal_. Besides, I think that _Terminal.app_ already starts as a login shell (it sources ~/.bash_login). Anyway, I hadn't followed the link at the bottom of the article about [login shells](https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login)... I didn't think about `su -l username`. That was quite useful, thanks.

Comment: Since we are on the topic... why not place the line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` directly in `~/.bashrc`? Is there a good reason?

Comment: sourcing can not be added to `.bashrc` in RVM 1.x - there are rare errors that would break in few occasions, the best way to make it work so far was sourcing only for login shell.

Answer (score 1):

you should check `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers` especially `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default` for binaries that can be used from `PATH` with no other settings in environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think I  found what was wrong. Could you check the answer I provided myself, please?