# RVM Wrapper not anymore in bin?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've installed a latest version of RVM, and the Wrapper are not anymore linked to the /usr/local/rvm/bin , exemple

this kind of link:
from /usr/local/rvm/bin

```
ruby-1.9.3-p374@global -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/ruby
```

is not anymore present in 1.25.18 (but the wrapper is still in rvm wrapper)

I have the same behavior with two installation (global install) and may be I've missed something.

Note that these are usefull to use in cron for instance. There is a similare question ( [rvm system install, bins not properly symlinked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835329/rvm-system-install-bins-not-properly-symlinked) ) but the discussion did not show a clear solution to the probleme

Answer (score 0):

Have you put this line into your `~/.bashrc` file?

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that this was on linux

Answer (score 0):

the wrappers are no more generated by default, it was confusing and lead to many problems, right now you can create the links with:

```
rvm wrappers 2.1.0
```

for the default ruby (for short names):

```
rvm wrappers 2.1.0 --no-prefix
```